# Nested Conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

Are nested conditions possible and grammatically correct?

- I would have told you about the party if I knew you would have come if I had told you Lucy would come if you came.

Or something like:

- Would you know, hadn't I told you that if I hadn't given you the papers, hadn't I taken them from John, that if I didn't have them you wouldn't pass your exam?

Comment: This makes my brain hurt.

Comment: "Buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo." is also a technically correct sentence with an actual meaning, but it similarly isn't a construction that is useful for conveying information.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Comment: I'm curious. Why else does English need conditionals and if-clauses?

Comment: By "why else", do you mean "why", or "why, other than to nest them repetitively to create extremely convoluted brain teasers"?

Comment: The second sentence is hard to parse and I am not yet convinced if it is even correct.

Comment: "Did you know you wouldn't pass the exam if I hadn't taken the papers from john, (hadn't) told you about it and (hadn't) given them to you?". Or better, although now I'm not sure about the tenses: " ... if I hadn't given you the papers, which I took from john, which I told you about?". @SovereignSun, do you remember that I told you to apply Database Normalization to sentence structure? This is such a case: you had multiple "primary keys", I turned them into secondary keys ... I think.

Comment: You need to know what you want to communicate before you build a complex sentence. Nested conditionals occur all the time - although peole say they don't. However - they only occur when people have a very clear understanding of what they want to say.

Comment: If you speak to a native speaker, and if you use a sentence like that (or this), and if the native speaker is willing to correct you, you will likely hear them say something like "huh?"

Comment: @Deolater In Russian it's very common in speech. "Ты бы пошла на вечеринку, не скажи я тебе, что, в связи с тем что у Димы появилось время, которое он по началу планировал занять музыкой, но потом, передумав, решил всё-таки сходить, что если ты туда пойдешь, то он тоже придет." and this is a very short one.

Comment: @SovereignSun I think the difference is that English tends to "unroll" the conditionals a bit more. We tend to make sentences like "If I had known that telling you that Lucy would come if you did would have been enough to make you come, I would have told you about the party." This is done more often in writing than in speech, because it is somewhat difficult (at least for me) to keep track of the logical structure of these sentences in English. Slightly off-topic, I wonder if Russian chess skill relates to the ease of expressing multi-step conditionals in this fashion.

Comment: @Deolater I'm not sure if everyone can do it but i can construct them instantly while speaking. In Russian i mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your first one is grammatically correct, but never ever write anything like that unless you are trying to make people's brains hurt, or for humour value or something. There are times you might want to do that, but they should generally be pretty rare. Better to use multiple sentences, or at least a more structured sentence than a chain of *would*s and *if*s.

The second one I can't actually parse easily, so I don't know whether it's valid or not.